# Using mixed formats parquet and JSON with AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have events encoded in JSON. Each event has nested within the object structure a numeric identifier which specifies the type of event.

I would like to store my events in S3 using parquet with a two column schema, the type of event and the raw JSON. This way whenever I need to make a query that uses only certain types of events I don't have to read each single event to find out what's its type.

To be clear, I wish to use parquet so that Athena can quickly fetch the events I care about by reading the first column, and then execute the query using the contents of the second column, the raw JSON events.

Is this possible? How? If not, any suggestions as to how can I save resources by accessing only the events I want to include in my query?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is organizing the into S3 bucket by event type and leverage that by partitioned table defined in Athena. More about athena partitioning [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html).